# Cheerio get images from json in a href

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm using cheerio module in Node.js to parse webpage. I have a problem because I would like to parse this code:

```
<div class="offer-photo" data-photo-urls='[{"small":"http://img02.allegroimg.pl/photos/64x48/61/16/25/71/6116257188","medium":"http://img02.allegroimg.pl/photos/400x300/61/16/25/71/6116257188"}]'>
        <a href="http://allegro.pl/klasyczne-okulary-lenonki-lustrzanki-kolory-etui-i6116257188.html" class="inner lazy-load" data-src="http://img02.allegroimg.pl/photos/128x96/61/16/25/71/6116257188">

        <noscript>
            <img src="http://img02.allegroimg.pl/photos/128x96/61/16/25/71/6116257188" alt="" />
        </noscript>

        </a>

    </div>
```

How can I get image using Cheerio from this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the element, then use the [`.data()`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#data-name-value-) method to get the data-attribute, and parse the JSON

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
$ = cheerio.load(html);

var element = $('.offer-photo').first();
var data    = element.data('photo-url');
var obj     = JSON.parse(data);
```

The data-attribute seems to be the only thing containing JSON, not the href from the anchor, it only contains an URL, which can be gotten with ?

```
var href = element.find('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting, the data attribute only contains two images (url's) ?